# Search all fields in Dublin Core with Apache solr

Tags: solr

[Here](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/ISLANDORA6122/APPENDIX+D+-+SOLR+SCHEMA+%28SEARCH%29+Term+Reference) described how can we configure Apache Solr to specify fields of search.

there is some fields like Type, Title, Subject and ... in Dublin Core but there is not something like All fields.

I know there is a way to handle this, because there is an implementation here: http://demo.projectblacklight.org/

Is there something like dc.all_field?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do this by using a [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) that copies all fields to another one:

```
<copyField source="*" dest="all"/>
```